# «Женское счастье», «мужское счастье»: как различаются эти выражения, какова их этимология?

Tags: значения, этимология, род, фраза

Что конкретно имеется в виду, когда говорят о "женском счастье", откуда это выражение пошло, и почему гораздо реже встречается "мужское счастье"? (речь здесь идет не об одноименных цветах)

Пример:

> "Знаменитая вдова во второй раз нашла свое **женское счастье** - Лидия
>   Федосеева-Шукшина и Бари Алибасов наконец-то расписались в ЗАГСе".
>   ([ссылка](https://lenta.ua/znamenitaya-vdova-vo-vtoroy-raz-nashla-svoe-zhenskoe-schaste-117/))

Возможно, имеется в виду вообще найти партнера, но тогда непонятен акцент на пол:

> "Андре Агасси [..] нашел наконец свое **мужское счастье** по имени
>   Штеффи Граф." ([ссылка](https://og.ru/sports/2015/07/13/upal-otzhalsya-pobedil))

Comment: Здесь нужен контекст, потому что пока что непонятно что конкретно вы имеете ввиду и как это конкретно связано с русским языком. Вообще говоря, вопрос про то, почему одно словосочетание более популярно чем другое (кстати, это тоже нужно обосновывать) - это всё-таки не вопрос про русский язык.

Comment: Не могу не отметить, что мне, как носителю, понятно, что имеется в виду, не требуя контекста. Это распространенная идиома, иногда употребляется в ироничном виде, иногда в прямом.

Comment: @ratschbumm мы никогда не должны исходить из предположения что точно знаем о чём речь - во-первых, мы можем ошибаться, думая, что поняли автора, а автор же на самом деле имел ввиду что-то немного (или совсем) другое,  во-вторых, наш личный опыт всё-таки ограничен, что очевидно одному носителю, не факт, что будет очевидно другому. Наконец, в-третьих,  кроме носителей языка есть люди, его изучающие - и желательно чтобы любой вопрос им был понятен сам по себе.

Comment: @shabunc Это верно, что автор мог иметь в виду что-то другое, но после какого-то уровня предполагать "на всякий случай", что так может быть — не менее контрпродуктивно, чем не предполагать ниже этого уровня. Примерно по той же причине, по которой с некоторого уровня развития не нужно с детьми сюсюкать и разговаривать с ними как с младенцами. Уровень речи в заданном вопросе я оцениваю как довольно высокий, хотя само словосочетание "гендерное счастье", будучи понятным, звучит невероятно коряво.

Comment: @ratschbumm а как обобщить мужское с женским счастье чтобы не коряво звучало? По теме, выходит что традиционные ценности закодированы в языке. В смысле, женщине вроде как не быть счастливой, если не найдет "женское счастье". *Kinder, Küche, Kirche*. Ну чем не Сепир-Уорф.

Comment: @J.Doe я принципиально против таких обобщений, что значит закодировано в языке? Есть некий пласт вокабуляра употребляемый определённым кругом лиц - ни больше ни меньше. Когда девушка говорит по-русски "вот, нашла богатого себе папика" - это закодировано в языке? Когда кто-то выражается на блатном жаргоне - это закодировано в языке?

Что такое в принципе в строгом определении "закодировано в языке"?

Comment: @J.Doe Можно сказать просто "нашел/нашла свое счастье". А в чем оно там у него/нее лично выражается, неважно. Главное, что его/ее представления встречают понимание у супруга/супруги. И да, если говорят, про женское счастье, это означает уже конкретный набор представлений, и раз это найденное счастье, то это то, к чему эта женщина стремилась. Или традиционные роли, с вашей точки зрения, обязательно означают что-то плохое? Если так, то тут я ничем не могу помочь.

Comment: "мужское счастье" это не устоявшееся выражение, а калька трансфер смысла употребленный автором, ссылка на "женское счастье". Если бы имел смысл в объединении, то можно сказать "человеческое счастье" и такое тоже есть, но оно не подразумевает что то конкретно или подразумевает широкий спектр вещей более индивидуальный в каждом конкретном случае. В обоих случаях речь о женитьбе, соответственно используется более специфический/узкий/точный вариант человеческого счастья указывающий  на конкретные обстоятельства женитьба в этих случаях.

Comment: Фактически, это не идиомы и не вопрос языковедения - а определенные моральные максимы и клише определенных носителей определенной морали. :> В этом смысле метафорически прозрачные - ж.счастье - счастье для женщин, м.счастье - счастье для мужчин. :>  Спрашивать конкретнее следует у носителей подобной морали, очевидно. Могу предположить, что "женское счастье" трактуется ими часто как "3K" - Kinder, Küche, Kirche  - "дети, кухня, церковь"; или тому подобное с вариациями...

Comment: В данном случае - "Знаменитая вдова во второй раз нашла свое женское счастье - Лидия Федосеева-Шукшина и Бари Алибасов наконец-то расписались в ЗАГСе" - что она нашла себе мужа.  Ну или любовь.

    "Андре Агасси [..] нашел наконец свое мужское счастье по имени Штеффи Граф." (ссылка)" - что он нашел свою идеальную женщину, очевидно :>
 -----
"непонятен акцент на пол:" - ну, как, минимум акцент на пол существует - потому что существует пол и его противоположный пол. :> Ж.счастье - мужчина; М. счастье - женщина. Для этих двух примеров.

Comment: ratschbumm, "хотя само словосочетание "гендерное счастье", будучи понятным, звучит невероятно коряво" - гы гы... просто дикий "политкорявый" нонсенс :> И как раз понятного тут - мало :> Сексуальное счастье - тогда уж понятнее

Answer (score 5):

Женское счастье, это отсылка к традиционным ценностьям, дом, уют, любящий муж, достаток, можно посвятить себя материнству и домашнему очагу. Иногда употребляется как "маленькое" или "тихое" "женское счастье". Это современное использование, а так, есть рассказ Чехова, (не того, что в Star Trek, а Антон Палыча) под названием "Женское счастье". [Прочесть тут](https://ru.wikisource.org/wiki/%D0%96%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%D0%B5_(%D0%A7%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B2))

В разрезе современного значения "мужское счастье" почти не употребяется, а редкие случаи, честно говоря, выглядят коряво. Видимо, это связано с общими представлениями что мужчина значительно более активен и не склонен к домашнему хозяйству и, если взять *в целом*, не может быть полностью удовлетворен подобной тихой, безмятежной жизнью.

Comment: благодарю за ответ! То есть, если исходить из достоверности изложенных фактов, из приведенных источников следует понимать, что Лидия Федосеева-Шукшина во второй раз стала домохозяйкой, а Андре Агасси стал домохозяином?

Comment: @J.Doe Вообще-то Агасси не бросил свою теннисную карьеру сразу после женитьбы, так что, скорее, это журналист так пошутил: возможно он нашёл упомянутые им мемуары Агасси чересчур, кхм, романтичными, ну или вроде того.

Comment: @J.Doe Не совсем так. Не обязательно рассматривать данное "счастье" только как обязательный список перечисленных мною признаков. Я лишь перечислил некие примеры, чтоб сформировать образ. На самом деле, это самое женское счастье можно найти и не будучи домохозяйкой, например при наличии прислуги, или даже не имея детей. Даже официальный брак может не быть зарегистрирован. Однако теплые, доверительные, порождающие спокойствие и уверенность отношения - это необходимость. Что до Агасси, я потому и написал, что обычно по отношению к мужчинам эта фраза выглядит несколько нелепо.

Comment: @J.Doe c Агасси это ироническое использование второго порядка - я бы так это назвал - это просто построенное по аналогии с женским счастьем словосочетание

Comment: "а Андре Агасси стал домохозяином? " - не-а. И вообще такое словосочетание, слово у нас не используется в таком контексте :>> Мужском. "Домохозяин" это владелец дома. :> householder. house owner; Никаких таких ассоциаций, как со словом "домохозяйка", тут нет. :>
________
Повторюсь к расшифровке примеров :  - что она нашла себе мужа, или любовь; - что он нашел свою идеальную женщину, очевидно :>

Answer (score 3):

My impression is that in Russia the gender roles are very distinct. So I would interpret *женское счастье* as happiness in the female role (as a wife and mother), but I am not a native speaker.

Comment: you got it right!

Comment: Though I'd replace *in Russia* with *in Russian language* (as in general a language does not necessary reflect the *modern state of a society*).

Comment: it more than roles, it also results in utilitarian circumstantial consequences, which in a good case may be very convenient.

Answer (score 1):

Выражение «женское счастье» — это отсылка к восприятию, что для женщины найти супруга — своего рода карьера. Успех мужчины — это что он сделал и где работает, успех женщины — это кто её муж и какая у неё семья. Я бы не сказал, что использование этого выражения есть непременно знак, что использующий его разделяет такое восприятие. Скорее, он считает его уместным для описания именно той ситуации, о которой идёт речь. То есть подразумевается, что эта вдова до какой-то степени разделяет подобные суждения о гендерных ролях.

Выражение «мужское счастье» — это новояз, как уже здесь говорили.

Выражения «гендерное счастье» просто нет, его невозможно понять.